# Importing local json data using lazy load in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, lazy-loading, react-lazy-load

I have a locally stored json in my project, which is an **array** containing around 200+ items.

Example: data.js

```
const data = [
  {
    title: 1
  },
  {
    title: 2 
  },
  ...
  {
    title: 200
  }
];
```

My Component:

```
import {data} from "../mocks/data.js";
```

I am thinking of a way to use the json data for sometime until I have a database setup, but importing 200+ records slows up the page.

Is there a way I can lazy load the locally json data?

Comment: Instead of storing it in a `.js` file, maybe you can do it by using hooks: `const data = use(import('./data.json'))`.

Comment: @chagatai do you have any examples, what is use here? Feel free post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your example is a JavaScript object, not a JSON.

Secondly, [The `use` hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/use) may help you in this problem.

```
import { use } from 'react';

const data = use(import('./data.json'))
```

Also, there is a 3rd-party module to read in JSON data called [`json-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader), which is already included in `create-react-app`.

```
import customData from '../customData.json';
```

IMHO, I don't think that importing 200+ records **in JSON** slows up the page dramatically, but nevertheless these solutions may help you once you convert your mock data to a JSON.

Comment: I agree with you, but since its server side rendering with next js I wanted to have first paint quickly and load the data instead of render blocking due to data,